# GNU Radio missing Osmocom. Cant even build it to install

Tags: gnuradio

I am trying to follow along with some Youtube tutorials by the maker of HackRF and when using GNU Radio it seems they no longer have Osmocom, or WX blocks. So I go to the repo found here https://github.com/osmocom/gr-osmosdr/tree/master , also note they dont have an  "issues" tab to ask questions in. Anyways I follow the instructions and get this failure:

```
CMake Error at /usr/lib/cmake/pybind11/pybind11Tools.cmake:165 (add_library):
  Target "osmosdr_python" links to target "sndfile::sndfile" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cmake/gnuradio/GrPybind.cmake:261 (pybind11_add_module)
  python/bindings/CMakeLists.txt:28 (GR_PYBIND_MAKE_OOT)


CMake Error at lib/CMakeLists.txt:51 (add_library):
  Target "gnuradio-osmosdr" links to target "sndfile::sndfile" but the target
  was not found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED
  target, or an ALIAS target is missing?
```

So I am not sure where to go from here. Is there a replacement to Osmocom? I noticed a "soapy" source called HackRF but it is so basic compared to the Osmocom one. I dont really understand how GNURadio works but nerfing a feature that is documented all over the internet in GNU Radio  tutorials seems odd.

Any ideas?

Comment: gr-osmosdr was never part of GNU Radio, always a separate package. WXGUI has been deprecated for a decade… you might need better tutorials.

Comment: and: an issue tracker is **not** for asking questions, it's for reporting bugs.

Comment: and: we didn't nerf anything, gr-osmosdr is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, gr-soapy is the what I'd recommend you use. It's not a "replacement", it's an alternative. But unlike gr-osmosdr (which was never part of GNU Radio), it's part of modern GNU Radio.

Your youtube tutorials must be really outdated if they still use WXGui (we've started telling people WXGUI was no longer maintained and will be removed about 10 years ago). That's a bad start. Instead, try to go through the official GNU Radio Academy at https://tutorials.gnuradio.org

> but it is so basic compared to the Osmocom one

What feature that the HackRF actually has and that is useful to you are you missing?